# Using CryptHashData On Very Large Input

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi, realbasic

I am trying to MD5 hash user-supplied data (a file) using The Crypto functions in AdvApi32. All is well and good unless the file is very large (hundreds of MB. or larger) in which case I eventually get an OutOfMemory exception.

I figured that the solution would be to make repeated calls to `CryptHashData` using the same `HashObject` and processing only (for example) 4096 bytes at a time.

This appears to work, but the returned hash is incorrect.

```
Function HashFile(File As FolderItem) As String
  Declare Function CryptAcquireContextW Lib "AdvApi32" (ByRef provider as Integer, container as Integer, providerName as WString, _
  providerType as Integer, flags as Integer) as Boolean
  Declare Sub CryptDestroyHash Lib "AdvApi32" (hashHandle as Integer )
  Declare Function CryptCreateHash Lib "AdvApi32" (provider as Integer, algorithm as Integer, key as Integer, flags as Integer, _
  ByRef hashHandle as Integer) as Boolean
  Declare Function CryptHashData Lib "AdvApi32" (hashHandle as Integer, data as Ptr, length as Integer, flags as Integer) as Boolean
  Declare Function CryptGetHashParam Lib "AdvApi32" (hashHandle as Integer, type as Integer, value as Ptr, ByRef length as Integer, _
  flags as Integer) as Boolean

  Const HP_HASHVAL = &h0002
  Const HP_HASHSIZE = &h0004
  Const MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
  Const PROV_RSA_FULL = 1
  Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = &h00000008
  Const CALG_MD5 = &h00008003

  Dim provider As Integer
  Dim hashHandle As Integer

  If Not CryptAcquireContextW(provider, 0, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0) Then
    If Not CryptAcquireContextW(provider, 0, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET) Then
      Raise New RuntimeException
    End If
  End If

  If Not CryptCreateHash(provider, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, hashHandle) Then
    Raise New RuntimeException
  End If

  Dim dataPtr As New MemoryBlock(4096)
  Dim bs As BinaryStream
  bs = bs.Open(File)
  dataPtr.StringValue(0, 4096) = bs.Read(4096)

  Do
    If CryptHashData(hashHandle, dataPtr, dataPtr.Size, 0) Then
      dataPtr = New MemoryBlock(4096)
      dataPtr.StringValue(0, 4095) = bs.Read(4096)
    End If
  Loop Until bs.EOF

  Dim size as Integer = 4
  Dim toss As New MemoryBlock(4)
  If Not CryptGetHashParam(hashHandle, HP_HASHSIZE, toss, size, 0) Then
    Raise New RuntimeException
  End If

  size = toss.UInt32Value(0)

  Dim hashValue As New MemoryBlock(size)
  If Not CryptGetHashParam(hashHandle, HP_HASHVAL, hashValue, size, 0) Then
    Raise New RuntimeException
  End If
  CryptDestroyHash(hashHandle)

  //Convert binary to hex
  Dim hexvalue As Integer
  Dim hexedInt As String
  Dim src As String = hashValue.StringValue(0, hashValue.Size)
  For i As Integer = 1 To LenB(src)
    hexvalue = AscB(MidB(src, i, 1))
    hexedInt = hexedInt + RightB("00" + Hex(hexvalue), 2)
  next

  Return LeftB(hexedInt, LenB(hexedInt))

End Function
```

What am I doing wrong here? The output I get is consistent, but wrong.

Comment: I don't think your code correctly handles the case where the file data length is not an exact multiple of 4096 bytes.

Comment: @David Schwartz Hmm. Good point! Let me make some tweaks to the code.

Comment: @David Schwartz that doesn't appear to fix it, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [that msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on C++ ?
Very similar answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that since you read the data in blocks of 4096 bytes - when the data is not a multiple of 4096 you endup including unwanted trailing 0's or possibly garbage values. Try `bs.Read(1)` instead of `bs.Read(4096)` in the loop: `Loop Until bs.EOF` in-order to test if correct hash is being calculated now. If successful adjust your loop to tackle the remainder (%4096) bytes separately.